# Creating a filter for a canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a plugin that has drawing features and I want to add a filter button. Right now, when the "grayscale" option is selected from a pull down list, the function  called filterImage is called. The make_base function shown in the code simply loads an image into the canvas. Currently the image appears in the canvas, but no grayscale is applied. How would I go about doing this? Can the make_base function (putting in an image) and grayscale filter function be called in the same function?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("art-board");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var selectObj = document.getElementById("filter");
var index = selectObj.selectedINdex;
var filter = selectObj[index].value;
make_base(canvas, context);

if(filter=="grayscale"){
    filterImage(canvas, context);
}

function filterImage(canvas, context){

     imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
     data = imageData.data,
     iLen = data.length;

      for (i = 0; i < iLen; i+=4) {
        avg = 0.3  * data[i] + 0.59 * data[i + 1] + 0.11 * data[i + 2];
        data[i] = avg + 100;
        data[i + 1] = avg + 50;
        data[i + 2] = avg + 255;
      }

      context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);    

 }
```

Comment: One error in the code you provided: `selectObj.selectedINdex;`should be modified to `selectObj.selectedIndex;`. Also, I assume your make_base function does load the image into a `new Image()` tag and actually only draws it to the canvas on its `onload` event. Your check for filter should be contained in this onload or the canvas will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I think there's a problem with your loop.
[I found working RGB values/code on HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/)

```
var r = d[i];
var g = d[i+1];
var b = d[i+2];
// CIE luminance for the RGB
// The human eye is bad at seeing red and blue, so we de-emphasize them.
var v = 0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b;
d[i] = d[i+1] = d[i+2] = v
```